# Viewing directory of a mapped drive

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, xp-cmdshell, datadir

I'm using the following query to view files/folders in a given directory. It works locally, but when trying to view a mapped drive I get...

```
"The system cannot find the path specified."
```

I have the permissions for the whole mapped drive set to the service account associated with SQL, but it is still not working.

```
declare @files table (ID int IDENTITY, FileName varchar(100))
insert into @files execute xp_cmdshell 'dir Z:\ /b'
select * from @files
```

End goal is to create a stored procedure that will transact specific file names into a table.

Comment: Use a UNC path (`\\Server\Share`) rather than a mapped drive. Drive mappings are specific the user/session.

Comment: @DanGuzman when I do so I'm getting `The network name cannot be found`

Comment: Do you see the share listed if you login the to SQL box interactively with the service account and run `NET VIEW \\server` from a command prompt?

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks I guess I might of overlooked something, but I'm going to be using the UNC path now thanks to you!

Comment: Glad you got it working. I should add that such tasks are better done in application code or script rather than T-SQL and `xp_cmdshell`.